# Swift optional or Implicit property on UIViewController subclass

Tags: ios, swift

I have a the following class

```
class Foo : UIViewController {
  var demo : SKView

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.demo = SKView(...)
    ...
    self.view.insertSubview(demo, atIndex: 0)
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
    self.demo.removeFromSuperView()
    self.demo = nil
  }
}
```

My question is, since I don't have an initializer on `Foo`, demo has to be either `?` or `!`. I have read many places that I should stay away from using `!`. In this case however, is there any reason to not use it? I'm not 100% clear on the downsides specifically on this case since the view itself will always be set on `viewDidLoad` and only unset on `viewWillDisappear`.

What is the most common pattern for these kind of properties on such classes? Properties that get set on `viewDidLoad` and will always have a value.

Comment: Regarding using ! It is discouraged if you are unwrapping an optional (i.e. ?). For unwrapping you should use one of the various other options. For a case like this, using ! is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that Swift enforces class members to always have a value upon initialization. By marking the variable `demo` with `!` or `?` you are telling the compiler that this variable can have the value `nil`, hence the optional notation.

In the context of iOS development, it's perfectly acceptable to mark `SKView` with `!` so you don't have to suffix each call to `demo` with `?`.

If `demo` is `nil` and you require a value to always be present then the app will crash during runtime which under many circumstances is in fact desirable.

```
class Foo : UIViewController {
  var demo : SKView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.demo = SKView(...)
    ...
    self.view.insertSubview(demo, atIndex: 0)
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
    self.demo.removeFromSuperView()
    self.demo = nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo: UIViewController {
    var demo: SKView = SKView()

    ...
}
```

100% it won't be nil since Foo().

Or you can override the init(), but I don't like that. If I'm sure I won't use the property before ViewDidLoad(), I prefer to writing the initialization in ViewDidLoad(), and mark as `var demo: SKView!`

Comment: The only downside to something like this is that if the property is particularly memory heavy or expensive to create you're now creating an extra one just to throw away. I'd prefer ! Over this I think. (Although I used to do this all the time).

Comment: @Fogmeister You are right. I prefer using `?` now, unless I'm definitely sure `demo` won't be nil and I'll use `!`.